# What is the syntax for declaring a constant string[char] AA?

Tags: constants, associative-array, literals, d

The following declaration:

```
const(string[char]) AA1 = [
    'a' : "fkclopel",
    'b' : "poehfftw"
];

void main(string args[]){}
```

gives me:

> C:...\temp_0186F968.d(1,27): Error: non-constant expression ['a':"fkclopel", 'b':"poehfftw"]

while it would work with other type kinds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialize associative array constants inside a module constructor:

```
const /+ or immutable +/ (string [char]) AA1;
static this () {
    AA1 = [
        'a' : "fkclopel",
        'b' : "poehfftw"
    ];
}

import std.stdio;
void main () {writeln (AA1);}
```

The [manual section](http://dlang.org/expression.html#AssocArrayLiteral) on associative array literals explicitly states that "An *AssocArrayLiteral* cannot be used to statically initialize anything.", though it does not give clues as to why it is so.

Comment: The reason is that in the current implementation (which is suboptimal in a number of ways), the associative array layout and other details are completely opaque to the compiler. An AA literal just calls a runtime function (file src/druntime/src/rt/aaA.d, function _d_assocarrayliteralTX) which is responsible for actually organizing the data. That function might not even exist at compile time, being linked later from a binary library. Since static data needs a known layout so the compiler can put it into the executable's data segment and this function is a black box, it can't be used for that.

Comment: It should be noted that this restriction will eventually go away, once there is a solid library implementation of associative arrays. There is currently work in progress to this effect, which seems to be nearing completion.